# User input and command line arguments

Tags: python, input, command-line-arguments

How do I have a Python script that can accept user input and how do I make it read in arguments if run from the command line?

Comment: The answer will depend upon your version of Python.  Python 3.x does this a little differently than Python 2.7

Comment: And Python 2.7 also does this a bit differently than the versions before 2.7, e.g. `argparse` instead of `optparse`.

Comment: Duplicate of [How do you read from stdin in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python), [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860/how-to-read-process-command-line-arguments). [Discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373879/how-should-we-handle-popular-canonicals-that-ask-two-separate-questions).

Comment: It's not really a duplicate of the first: user input comes from `/dev/tty`, which is no always the same as standard input.

Comment: Concordant with the meta discussion cited by @user202729, I have cleaned up other questions that were linked here as a duplicate (in most cases, by changing them to link to one of the other two canonicals), and cast the first delete vote.

Answer (score 619, accepted):

To read user input you can try [the `cmd` module](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/cmd.html) for easily creating a mini-command line interpreter (with help texts and autocompletion) and [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) ([`input`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#input) for Python 3+) for reading a line of text from the user.

```
text = raw_input("prompt")  # Python 2
text = input("prompt")  # Python 3
```

Command line inputs are in `sys.argv`. Try this in your script:

```
import sys
print (sys.argv)
```

There are two modules for parsing command line options: [<s>`optparse`</s>](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/optparse.html) (deprecated since Python 2.7, use [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) instead) and [`getopt`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/getopt.html). If you just want to input files to your script, behold the power of [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/fileinput.html).

The [Python library reference](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/) is your friend.

Comment: `raw_input` was renamed to `input` in Python 3.x - [documentation here](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)

Comment: My favourite source for this: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_command_line_arguments.htm
and this looks good too:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/python-command-line-arguments-argv-example/

Comment: sys.argv needs to be supplied with argument number, if suppose you pass a parameter as a value eg. python file_name.py 2017-02-10 and you want to use the date , it should be sys.argv[1] else it will be a list such as [file_name.py,2017-02-10]

Comment: This won't read from tty if standard input comes from somewhere else. The question doesn't make it clear what should happen in that case.

Answer (score 518):

```
var = raw_input("Please enter something: ")
print "you entered", var
```

Or for Python 3:

```
var = input("Please enter something: ")
print("You entered: " + var)
```

Comment: It should be noted that you don't have to import `raw_input`, it's a builtin function.

Comment: You don't have to use str() in print concatenation since all entered data will be str(ing) type by default (even numbers).

Comment: This does not work well: it reads from standard input, which is not always a tty.

Comment: @reinierpost What do you mean? There are certainly other ways to read input, too, but this works fine in the terminal. Some IDEs might have trouble because they don't let you interact with a process which reads stuff from stdin, but then that's more of a flaw of those IDEs.

Comment: @tripleee: All of my scripts are written to write their output to stdout, so I can redirect it to file or to a pipe. When these scripts ask questions to the user, they must go to tty (the user), not to the file or pipe (stdout). Likewise, the user's answers should be read from tty even if the script is reading stdin from elsewhere (although that use case is rare enough that none of my scripts need to make this distinction).

Answer (score 214):

`raw_input` is no longer available in Python 3.x.  But `raw_input` was renamed `input`, so the same functionality exists.

```
input_var = input("Enter something: ")
print ("you entered " + input_var)
```

[Documentation of the change](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins)

Comment: In Python 2.7, input() doesn't convert values to strings.  So if you try to do this:
input_variable1 = input ("Enter the first word or phrase: "), 

you will get an error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
    return eval(raw_input(prompt))
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'bad' is not defined

Comment: input_var = input ("Press 'E' and 'Enter' to Exit: ")                  NameError: name 'e' is not defined                                    I am using Python 2.5. How, I can overcome this error.

Comment: You can avoid the Traceback notice by using the following import which comes with Python 2.7:
`import fileinput
result=[]
for line in fileinput.input():
 result.append(line)`

Comment: Here is more of the history and the rationale: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3111/

Answer (score 35):

The best way to process command line arguments is the [`argparse` module.](https://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html)

Use `raw_input()` to get user input.  If you import the [`readline module`](https://docs.python.org/library/readline.html) your users will have line editing and history.

Comment: readline only available on unix out of the box though.

Comment: argparse is the new optparse

Comment: It's hard to imagine a sentence where "best" and `argparse` can be combined. It is the standard argument parser, but it is complex and hairy, and huge overkill if you simply want to loop over `sys.argv[1:]`

Comment: Thanks for recommending argparse. A great improvement over argument parsing I used many years ago in C. Much better than any quick hand-coded stuff I ever tried, even for simple command lines with just a few options, and --help is built in for free!

Answer (score 21):

This simple program helps you in understanding how to feed the user input from command line and to show help on passing invalid argument.

```
import argparse
import sys

try:
     parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
     parser.add_argument("square", help="display a square of a given number",
                type=int)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    #print the square of user input from cmd line.
    print args.square**2

    #print all the sys argument passed from cmd line including the program name.
    print sys.argv

    #print the second argument passed from cmd line; Note it starts from ZERO
    print sys.argv[1]
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print e
```

1) To find the square root of 5

```
C:\Users\Desktop>python -i emp.py 5
25
['emp.py', '5']
5
```

2) Passing invalid argument other than number

```
C:\Users\bgh37516\Desktop>python -i emp.py five
usage: emp.py [-h] square
emp.py: error: argument square: invalid int value: 'five'
<type 'exceptions.SystemExit'>
```

Answer (score 19):

Careful not to use the `input` function, unless you know what you're doing. Unlike `raw_input`, `input` will accept any python expression, so it's kinda like `eval`

Answer (score 13):

Use 'raw_input' for input from a console/terminal.

if you just want a command line argument like a file name or something e.g.

```
$ python my_prog.py file_name.txt
```

then you can use sys.argv...

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

sys.argv is a list where 0 is the program name, so in the above example sys.argv[1] would be "file_name.txt"

If you want to have full on command line options use the optparse module.

Pev

Answer (score 10):

If you are running Python <2.7, you need [optparse](http://docs.python.org/library/optparse.html), which as the doc explains will create an interface to the command line arguments that are called when your application is run.

However, in Python ≥2.7, optparse has been deprecated, and was replaced with the [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html) as shown above. A quick example from the docs...

> The following code is a Python program that takes a list of integers
>   and produces either the sum or the max:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print args.accumulate(args.integers)
```

Answer (score 7):

As of Python <del>3.2</del> 2.7, there is now [argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html) for processing command line arguments.

Comment: argparse has also been backported and is available on PyPi http://pypi.python.org/pypi/argparse/1.2.1

Answer (score 7):

If it's a 3.x version then just simply use:

```
variantname = input()
```

For example, you want to input 8:

```
x = input()
8
```

x will equal 8 but it's going to be a string except if you define it otherwise.

So you can use the convert command, like:

```
a = int(x) * 1.1343
print(round(a, 2)) # '9.07'
9.07
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2:

```
data = raw_input('Enter something: ')
print data
```

In Python 3:

```
data = input('Enter something: ')
print(data)
```

Comment: This duplicates earlier answers without adding anything.

Answer (score 2):

```
import six

if six.PY2:
    input = raw_input

print(input("What's your name? "))
```

Comment: Perhaps emphasize that `import six` is a facility for creating code which is compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3. These days, you probably don't need that if you are writing new code; just focus on Python 3.

Comment: Agreed! I can't remember the last time I used Python 2.