# Python method for storing list of bytes in network (big-endian) byte order to file (little-endian)

Tags: python, file-io, binary, endianness, byte

My present task is to dissect tcpdump data that includes P2P messages and I am having trouble with the piece data I acquire and write to a file on my x86 machine. My suspicion is I have a simple endian-ness issue with the bytes I write to to file.

I have a list of bytes holding a piece of P2P video read and processed using python-pcapy package BTW.

`bytes = [14, 254, 23, 35, 34, 67, etc... ]`

I am looking for a way to store these bytes, presently held in a list in my Python application to a file.

Currently I write the pieces as follows:

```
def writePiece(self, filename, pieceindex, bytes, ipsrc, ipdst, ts): 
    file = open(filename,"ab")
    # Iterate through bytes writing them to a file if don't have piece already 
    if not self.piecemap[ipdst].has_key(pieceindex):
        for byte in bytes: 
            file.write('%c' % byte)
        file.flush()
        self.procLog.info("Wrote (%d) bytes of piece (%d) to %s" % (len(bytes), pieceindex, filename))

    # Remember we have this piece now in case duplicates arrive 
    self.piecemap[ipdst][pieceindex] = True

    # TODO: Collect stats 
    file.close()
```

As you can see from the for loop, I write the bytes to the file in the same order as I process them from the wire (i.e. network or big-endian order).

Suffice to say, the video which is the payload of the pieces does not playback well in VLC :-D

I think I need to convert them to little-endian byte order but am not sure the best way to approach this in Python.

**UPDATE**

The solution that worked out for me (writing P2P pieces handling endian issues appropriately) was:

```
def writePiece(self, filename, pieceindex, bytes, ipsrc, ipdst, ts): 
    file = open(filename,"r+b")
    if not self.piecemap[ipdst].has_key(pieceindex):
        little = struct.pack('<'+'B'*len(bytes), *bytes) 
        # Seek to offset based on piece index 
        file.seek(pieceindex * self.piecesize)
        file.write(little)
        file.flush()
        self.procLog.info("Wrote (%d) bytes of piece (%d) to %s" % (len(bytes), pieceindex, filename))

    # Remember we have this piece now in case duplicates arrive 
    self.piecemap[ipdst][pieceindex] = True

    file.close()
```

The key to the solution was usage of Python struct module as suspected and in particular:

```
    little = struct.pack('<'+'B'*len(bytes), *bytes)
```

Thanks to those who responded with helpful suggestions.

Comment: Bytes have no endianity - only types which consist of several bytes (i.e. 16bit, 32bit etc.) can be big-endian or little-endian. Therefore, currently your question is meaningless...

Comment: is this definitely always true though? is it not possible for a byte to have the LSB at the left end of a byte on some piece of hardware but at the right for another piece of hardware? surely, theoretically one can have a little endian byte and a big endian byte?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use an [array.array](http://docs.python.org/library/array.html#module-array):

```
from array import array
f.write(array('B', bytes))
```

instead of

```
f.write(struct.pack('<'+'B'*len(bytes), *bytes))
```

which when tidied up a little is

```
f.write(struct.pack('B' * len(bytes), *bytes))
# the < is redundant; there is NO ENDIANNESS ISSUE
```

which if len(bytes) is "large" might be better as

```
f.write(struct.pack('%dB' % len(bytes), *bytes))
```

Answer (score 2):

To save yourself some work you might like to use a [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#bytearray) (Python 2.6 and later):

```
b = [14, 254, 23, 35]
f = open("file", 'ab')
f.write(bytearray(b))
```

This does all the converting of your 0-255 values into bytes without the need for all the looping.

I can't see what your problem is otherwise without more information. If the data really is byte-wise then endianness isn't an issue, as others have said.

(By the way, using `bytes` and `file` as  variable names isn't good as it hide the built-ins of the same name).

Comment: I am limited to Python 2.5.4 for this project. Thanks for the insight into bytearray though Scott.

Answer (score 0):

This may have been answered previously in [Python File Slurp w/ endian conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632673/python-file-slurp-w-endian-conversion).

Comment: Thanks for this reference. The numpy-based method described is very concise and speedy.