# How to make a python script "pipeable" in bash?

Tags: python, pipe

I wrote a script and I want it to be *pipeable* in bash.  Something like:

```
echo "1stArg" | myscript.py
```

Is it possible? How?

Comment: [How would you do the same thing in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51000239/4575793)

Answer (score 80, accepted):

See this simple `echo.py`:

```
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    for line in sys.stdin:
        sys.stderr.write("DEBUG: got line: " + line)
        sys.stdout.write(line)
```

running:

```
ls | python echo.py 2>debug_output.txt | sort
```

output:

```
echo.py
test.py
test.sh
```

debug_output.txt content:

```
DEBUG: got line: echo.py
DEBUG: got line: test.py
DEBUG: got line: test.sh
```

Comment: The way the loop is written (`while True`…) is both incorrect and certainly not pythonic.  In fact, an empty input line will break the loop.  A simple and standard solution is to read standard input with `for line in sys.stdin`.   Plus, the initial `line = ''` is completely superfluous.

Comment: Great!  I took the liberty to indent your code with the standard 4 spaces (see PEP 8) instead of the original 2 spaces that you used.

Answer (score 21):

I'll complement the other answers with a *grep* example that uses [fileinput](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) to implement the typical behaviour of UNIX tools: 1) if no arguments are specified, it reads data from stdin; 2) many files can be specified as arguments; 3) a single argument of `-` means stdin.

```
import fileinput
import re
import sys

def grep(lines, regexp):
    return (line for line in lines if regexp.search(line))

def main(args):
    if len(args) < 1:
        print("Usage: grep.py PATTERN [FILE...]", file=sys.stderr)
        return 2 

    regexp = re.compile(args[0])
    input_lines = fileinput.input(args[1:])

    for output_line in grep(input_lines, regexp):
        sys.stdout.write(output_line)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    sys.exit(main(sys.argv[1:]))
```

Example:

```
$ seq 1 20 | python grep.py "4"
4
14
```

Answer (score 11):

In your Python script you simply [read from `stdin`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python).

Answer (score 5):

Everything that reads from stdin is "pipeable". Pipe simply redirects stdout of former program to the latter.