# Python 2.7: run an external program and parse its output (while the ext program runs)

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, stream, subprocess

I want to write a Python program that launches an external program ET --not written by me-- and uses its output to store perform some calculations.

I know that the module subprocess and its call() method can be used. My problem however is that the output of ET is huge (if I launch the program in a shell and redirect its output to a file, I get a file with 25GB size.).

Therefore I would like to be able to perform actions on the output of ET as they are "produced" and avoid saving a huge file.

How can I do this? If there are multiple ways, what are the issues to consider to chose the best choice for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subprocess should take care of your needs.
http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess

```
p = subprocess.Popen("millions.exe", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
i = 0
for line in p.stdout:
     i+=1
```

millions is a quick test program I wrote to print out numbers from 0 to 9999999, just to take a while and generate a lot of output.

Another option to think about is using command line piping. You could use sys.stdin in order to make it possible to pipe the output from the program into your python script.

[How to make a python script "pipeable" in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429966/how-to-make-a-python-script-pipeable-in-bash?lq=1)

Is an example of how to make this work.