# Parsing input argv json string

Tags: python, json, linux

I want to parse the output of a linux `jq` call into a python script that will decode the output `jq` json str and do things with it.

The output of my `jq` call `jq '.geometry' myJson.json` is something like this:

```
{
  "coordinates": [
    [
      [
        5,
        2
      ],
      [
        5.4,
        3
      ],
      [
        3,
        2.1
      ]
    ]
  ],
  "crs": {
    "properties": {
      "name": "foo"
    },
    "type": "name"
  },
  "type": "Polygon"
}
```

I have written a small python executable that decodes the output json string into python objects and then do things:

```
import collections
import json
import sys
import logging

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        geoJsonStr = str(sys.argv[1:])
        print geoJsonStr ## This for some reason only prints an empty slice '[]'
        data = json.loads(geoJsonStr)
        coordinates = data['coordinates'] ## TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
        ## Do things here

    except ValueError as e:
        logging.error(e.message)
        exit(1)
```

This is how I try to call it:

```
jq '.geometry' geoJson.json | myPythonProgram
```

However I am getting some python errors as noted in my code snippet above. I'm thinking it's the way that I am passing the `jq` output into my python executable. Somehow the entire json string isn't being picked up as an `argv` argument.

My first error is the `print GeoJsonStr` prints out an empty `[]` slice from `argv[1:]`. So I am probably incorrectly passing the json string into the python script. The subsequent error is:

```
coordinates = data['coordinates']
```

`TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str`

This is probably more or less because there was nothing to decode.

Comment: If you're getting errors, you need to include them here.

Comment: Possibly asking the same thing as [How to make a python script "pipeable" in bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429966/how-to-make-a-python-script-pipeable-in-bash) Perhaps that question will help

Answer (score 1):

When you use a pipe to send data to a program, you can access the data via stdin, not with as an argument in argv.

For example, suppose you had the following program:

foo.py:

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.read()
print "I got", len(data), "characters!"
```

Piping some data into it would give you output like this:

```
$ echo "foobar" | python foo.py
I got 6 characters!
```

Note that in this example, the call to python contains an argument (foo.py) that is completely separate from the input.

In your particular case you could read stdin directly like the above example, or pass `sys.stdin` directly as an argument to `json.load`:

```
import sys
...
obj = json.load(sys.stdin)
print obj
```

The output should look like so:

```
$ jq '.geometry' geoJson.json | python myPythonProgram.py
{u'crs': {u'type': u'name', u'properties': {u'name': u'foo'}}, u'type': u'Polygon', u'coordinates': [[[5, 2], [5.4, 3], [3, 2.1]]]}
```