# How to make a pipeable bash script

Tags: bash, pipe

I am working on a bash package called Tools, and I am trying to make a bash script that you can pipe trough to pass all output of a command to /dev/null.

Example:

```
cat myfile | null
```

null being the command in Tools.

And then it would output nothing. I know how to redirect output to /dev/null or other places, but, how do I make a pipe-able script to do that.

My current placeholder code:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo $1 &> /dev/null
```

Execution format:

```
null cat\ myfile
```

The backslash is an escape character so that bash knows that it is one argument, not two; Arguments are usually separated by spaces

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work:

```
somecommand | null
```

You would just need your `null` script to contain:

```
cat > /dev/null
```

`cat` reads from stdin and writes to stdout, which in this case you have redirected to `/dev/null`.

Note that this will not redirect stderr, because the pipe symbol (`|`) only redirects stdout. You can use `|&` to redirect both stdout and stderr, as in:

```
somecommand |& null
```

The real question, though, is why bother with this? You can just as easily run:

```
somecommand > /dev/null
```

Or:

```
somecommand >& /dev/null
```

---

**UPDATE**

Wow, bash 3.2?  That's too old.  That version of bash doesn't have support for the `|&` operator.  You can accomplish the same thing like this:

```
somecommand 2>&1 | null
```

That says "redirect stderr to stdout, and then redirect stdout to a pipe".

Comment: Well, why cant you just cat &> /dev/null

Comment: @PythonDude29 *... because the pipe symbol (`|`) only redirects stdout.*

Comment: What is the difference between "outputs it to /dev/null" and "omits the output"? Those sound like synonyms to me.

Comment: It does work actually i just suck at testing, the |& pipe outputs: Unexpected token near '&'

Comment: That suggests you're not actually using `bash` but instead some other Bourne-like shell.

Comment: Ok I am running Mac OS X 10.5.8, so, It is really old :P

Comment: I entered "bash" and I have bash 3.2, it still outputs the same thing

Comment: I can see now the use of pipeable scripts, and now I understand how grep works :D

Comment: What's the point of the useless use of cat? Just `exec >/dev/null` and save a process today.

Comment: Because then I would need to explain what `exec` does and I was aiming for simplicity.  But you do you.

Answer (score 1):

Too many useless uses of cats here. All your script needs to do is

```
exec >/dev/null
```

And if you want to nuke stderr as well,

```
exec >/dev/null 2>/dev/null
```

Note that `exec` without a command makes its redirections apply for the remainder of the script.

Comment: The script would only have a single input stream. There is no point in redirecting standard error.

Comment: @Kusalananda That is correct; let the second `exec` serve as an example for redirecting multiple file descriptors in scripts with a different purpose.