# How to write a program in python that will process a text stream?

Tags: python, inputstream, text-processing

I am sorry if this is a repeat question. How do I write a python script to process data as a stream of line? I need to do this because the files that I am processing are huge, and I would rather not read the file into the memory.

I know that you can potentially read one line of the file at a time, but I want something that will process a text stream.

Comment: What's the difference between reading "a stream of lines" and "read one line of the file at a time"?

Comment: Well, in the input stream, i dont care where the line comes from.  I am not doing the file-handling for the input.  When I say read oneline at a time, it means that I know the file, my program is responsible for opening and closing it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could just read the data from `stdin`, as described in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python/1450398#1450398). This would look like that in code:

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    # do suff
```

If you want to process a file, then just call the script like this (on Unix platforms):

```
cat file.txt | python script.py
```

You can of course pipe the output of any other program in there too.

Answer (score 7):

Your case sounds pretty much exactly what [the fileinput module](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) was designed for. That way you can do:

```
python script.py file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt
```

and in `script.py`

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    # do stuff here
```

The added bonus for using fileinput is that you can do roughly the same thing Space_C0wb0y suggested adding a dash as the first parameter:

```
python script.py - < file.txt
```

or

```
cat file.txt | python script.py -
```

fileinput is mentioned in the answers to the question linked by Space_C0wb0y, I just figured I'd spell out how it can be leveraged.

Answer (score 0):

```
f = open('somefile.txt')
for line in f:
    process(line)
```

Actually, `f` can be anything that is iterable, so for example a list of strings or even `sys.stdin` if you wanted to read from standard input.

Comment: You are right, that was assumed. But if that is all the program is doing (reading lines and calling `process()` on them) then there is no point in explicitly closing the file

Comment: People who ask questions like this one are usually beginners, and it is therefore prudent to show them only the best of practices, because they do not know better.