# Optional stdin in Python with argparse

Tags: python, stdin, argparse

I found the very useful syntax

```
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input-file', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default='-')
```

for specifying an input file or using stdin—both of which I want in my program. However, the input file is not always required. If I'm not using `-i` or redirecting input with one of

```
$ someprog | my_python_prog
$ my_python_prog < inputfile
```

I don't want my Python program to wait for input. I want it to just move along and use default values.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The standard library [documentation for argparse](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#nargs) suggests this solution to allow optional input/output files:

```
>>> parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
>>> parser.add_argument('infile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'),
...                     default=sys.stdin)
>>> parser.add_argument('outfile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
...                     default=sys.stdout)
>>> parser.parse_args(['input.txt', 'output.txt'])
Namespace(infile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='input.txt' encoding='UTF-8'>,
          outfile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='output.txt' encoding='UTF-8'>)
>>> parser.parse_args([])
Namespace(infile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdin>' encoding='UTF-8'>,
          outfile=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' encoding='UTF-8'>)
```

Comment: I'm absolutely bewildered. OP said the input file was not always required. So why is `infile` specified first? Why are these positional anyway? Lastly, why the heck wouldn't OP's code work? The `argparse` tutorial seems to imply that it should work just fine...

Comment: @2rs2ts _why is `infile` specified first?_  — Particular ordering of the arguments is just a convention, you usually expect first argument to specify an input and second specify output. _Why are these positional anyway?_ — Because of author's preference. Nothing wrong with this usage of positional arguments. Might be a bit awkward to use in scenario when you want to read from stdin and write to a file, i.e.`app.py - outfile` but other than that positional argument would work just fine. _Why the heck wouldn't OP's code work?_ — it actually works just fine :)

Comment: @Mr.Deathless `app.py - outfile` explains it perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 25):

Use [isatty](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.isatty) to [detect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077113/how-do-i-detect-whether-sys-stdout-is-attached-to-terminal-or-not) whether your program is in an interactive session or reading from a file:

```
if not sys.stdin.isatty(): # Not an interactive device.
  # ... read from stdin
```

However, for the sake of consistency and reproducability, consider following the norm and reading from stdin if the filename is `-`. You may want to consider to let the [`fileinput`](http://docs.python.org/library/fileinput.html) module handle that.

Answer (score 21):

Building on top of [the answer regarding TTY detection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7576567/393280), to answer the question explicitly:

```
import sys
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-i', '--input-file', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=(None if sys.stdin.isatty() else sys.stdin))
```