# Read from stdin or input file with argparse

Tags: python, file-io, argparse

I'd like to use `argparse` to read from *either* `stdin` *or* an input file. In other words:

- If an input file is given, read that.
- If not, read from stdin *only* if it's not the terminal. (i.e. a file is being piped in)
- If neither of these criteria are satisfied, signal to argparse that the inputs aren't correct.

I'm asking for behavior similar to what's described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7576525/915501), but I want `argparse` to recognize no file as a failed input.

Comment: Does `fileinput` module help at all?

Answer (score 1):

Using the information from the question you linked to, what about using `sys.stdin.isatty()` to check if the instance your program is being run is part of a pipeline, if not, read from input file, otherwise read from `stdin`. If the input file does not exist or `stdin` is empty throw an error.

Hope that helped.

Comment: I was trying to do something like that. Of course it's possible to check for an empty input after `argparse` runs, but it's slightly more ugly (especially since you have to call `print_usage()` manually to get behavior like you'd get when you omit a required argument).

Comment: Yeah...not very pythonic. I'm surprised non of the veterans have yet answered with an elegant solution. Usually they post before I have even gotten my head around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend just settings `nargs='?'` and then handling the case of a Nonetype separately. According to [the official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#filetype-objects), *"FileType objects understand the pseudo-argument '-' and automatically convert this into sys.stdin for readable FileType objects and sys.stdout for writable FileType objects"*. So just give it a dash if you want stdin.

### Example

```py
import argparse
import sys
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('inputfile', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'))
if not inputfile:
    sys.exit("Please provide an input file, or pipe it via stdin")
```