# Testing Django commands file or stdin

Tags: python, django, django-commands

I am writing a django command that takes a bunch of input and processes it.

It seems natural that because of the volume of the data, the input should either come in as a file or as stdin.

I would like to easily test it, and by easily, I mean, without having to create a bunch of files in my test environment.

Now, I remember somewhere (can't find it properly documented, [but I did find the "PR"](https://gist.github.com/bmispelon/ad5a2c333443b3a1d051)), that the "-" is supposed to read from stdin, but I can't get it to work.

It seems the command should do something like this:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("foo", type=file)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        file = options["foo"]
        # Then read the file, and process it
```

But then when I run the command on the command line, it doesn't like the `-` parameter (says it isn't a file).

The [command docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/#management-commands-output.admonition.note) recommend writing to `self.stdout` for better testing. I tried something similar for `self.stdin` but couldn't get that to work either.

Assuredly this is a common pattern, but I couldn't find any good helps on how to do this best. It seems like "There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.", but I can't find it. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I would create a bunch of files as my test fixture, if that solves the problems. I don't think that way is bad

Comment: How did you write the tests? Where is the "-"?

Comment: @Ming I want my tests to be simple, so they'll mostly just be files with just one line in them, even a single word, and that seems annoying to have to go look in the file to see what's inside. A test that passes a single item seems much cleaner.

Comment: @Ming my tests of the "-" were run on the command line (edited question to better reflect that)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having a look at [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) for the `type=` argument to add_argument, it says "the argparse module provides the factory FileType".

So I did the following and `./manage.py test_stdin -` then worked as you'd expect.

```py
import argparse

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("foo", type=argparse.FileType('r'))

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        input_file = options["foo"]
        while True:
            line = input_file.readline()
            if len(line.strip()) == 0:
                break
            else:
                self.stdout.write("I just read %d chars, line %s" % (len(line),line))
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks. `argparse.FileType('r')` isn't very intuitive. I was (obviously) hoping for something simpler like `file`. Thanks.

Comment: It's because `file` doesn't have special handling for '-', whereas looking at the source for argparse it has a check for `if string == '-'` and returns stdin if the mode is 'r'. Makes sense when you realise '-' is a convention in executable args and not elsewhere. But thanks for the accept, was fun working this out.

Answer (score 3):

Django command argument parser is a wrapping of [argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html) module. According to this post: [Optional stdin in Python with argparse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576525/optional-stdin-in-python-with-argparse), you can define an argument to accept `stdin` or a actual file as an input.

Sample command for your reference:

#### management/commands/stdintest.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
import sys
import argparse


class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Test stdin as input file'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('foo', nargs='?', type=argparse.FileType('r'), default=sys.stdin)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        foo = options.get('foo')
        sys.stdout.write(foo.read())
```

You can call the command without specifying the input file, and the command will grab input from stdin

```
$ python manage.py stdintest
1234
abcd     <- press ctrl+d to end stdin input
1234
abcd
```

or specify the `foo` argument with an actual file

```
$ echo '12345' > test.txt
$ python manage.py stdintest test.txt
```

I am not sure is that what you need. If I have misunderstood, please leave a comment. Hope it would help.

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks, but the other answer is slightly more of what I asked for.