# Python Command Line input?

Tags: python

My Python script will run a bunch of shell scripts that output either `200 SOLUTIONS_REVISION` or `400 SOLUTIONS_REVISION` when run. The `200` in the output indicates success and the `400` indicates failure.

How can I capture these "returned" strings as `str`s in the Python code, for further processing?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python

Comment: This question was originally closed as a duplicate of one about reading from the standard input. OP described the question as being about reading from the command line, which would be another duplicate. However, **both are wrong**. The question - as determined by the answerer - is **actually** about reading **from the standard output of a subprocess**. Which... is yet another duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're going to run the command from your Python script then you want to look at [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) with its `stdout` arguments. If you're going to run both that script and the Python script from a separate shell script then you want to pipe from one to the next and then read from `sys.stdin`.

Comment: well the python script will be calling the shell script (like 120 different ones). And then I'll be getting the input after each shell script (well thats the idea anyways)