# Python3: Using input() with stdin, like in hackerrank

Tags: python

I have an input file ("abc.in") which I will like to read each line as `input()`, exactly like how it works on hackerrank and other online coding platforms.

I have seen solutions replicating the same functionality by [piping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816239/python3-using-input-how-to-read-multiple-lines-from-pipe-stdin), [fileinput and sys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python/38670261#38670261) etc. On hackerrank I can just use `input()` to store one line of the input file as a variable. How do I do that locally? Do I store the files in the same place, what command do I use to run this in the terminal?

I thought this would be easy, but somehow I can't seem to figure out how to do it after trying for some time. Apologies if the answer was obvious.

Any help provided is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can redirect the stdin with `<` on command line. Let's say you have following input stored to file `data.in`:

```
line1
line2
```

And you have following code stored to `test.py`:

```
print(1, input())
print(2, input())
```

Then you can run the script with redirected stdin:

```
~$ python3 test.py < data.in
1 line1
2 line2
```

If you want to save the output to a file you can redirect stdout as well:

```
~$ python3 test.py < data.in > data.out
```

Comment: Thank you! I am new to HackerRank and new to using inputs in the way HackerRank uses them for Python. You've saved me a lot of time in trying to figure this out!