# Read from pipe without an end

Tags: python, shell, command, pipe, stdin

I have problems of reading with python from `stdin` if I have a pipe with continuous data stream which doesn't stop.

As an example I have **data_stream.py**

```py
import time

i = 0
while True:
    print(i)
    i += 1
    time.sleep(2)
```

Now I try to read the data with the file **read_data.py**

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print(line)
```

When I try to run it with `python3 data_stream.py | python3 read_data.py` I get no result because `data_stream.py` did not finished.
How can I read from `data_stream.py` while it is still running?

Comment: This code doesn't run, because (a) you haven't imported `sys`, and (b) you don't have a colon on the end of that `for`. Without code that demonstrates your problem, we can't debug your code. Also, it would really help to know what platform you're on. Please read [mcve] in the help for guidance on what goes into a question.

Comment: This is your answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091413/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python-from-a-pipe-which-has-no-ending?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Pipes **always** feed into the reading program while the writing one is still running, but that doesn't mean that writes are always immediately visible to readers without either a certain length limit being met or an explicit flush. (In *most* languages, writes to stdout are line-buffered by default when stdout is a TTY, but block-size-chunk buffered by default when it's a FIFO). See [BashFAQ #9](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/009) for a non-Python-specific discussion of the issue at hand.

Answer (score 1):

You must “flush” the stdout in data_stream.py and “readline” from read_data.py.
The complete code are below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  data_stream.py

import sys
import time

i = 0
while True:
    print(i)
    i += 1
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(2)
```

And the code for read_data.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
#  read_data.py

import sys

# Now I try to read the data with the file read_data.py

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    print (line),
```

Best Regards,

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), see the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and within that the bullet point regarding questions which "...have already been asked and answered many times before".

Comment: Many thanks Charles, I'm new here. And eventually I make some mistake.