# Get current content of Popen with subprocess.PIPE output redirection

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I'm running a certain bash script via `subprocess.Popen`. This is a simplified version of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "I want to read this"
echo "And also this"
echo "Maybe even this"

while :; do
    sleep 100
    echo "But probably not this"
done
```

I'd like to obtain its output after running it, before it concludes. I need to do this without using 3rd-party libraries. I've tried a bunch of solutions such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2813530/5769814) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45223675/5769814). However, none of these solutions worked for me (they all hang when they reach the end of the output). What I have currently is this:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, TimeoutExpired

with Popen(['./script.sh'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) as process:
    try:
        output, _ = process.communicate(timeout=5)
    except TimeoutExpired:
        pass
    return process, output
```

However, this obviously also doesn't capture the output, since the `TimeoutExpired` exception is raised before assigning to `output`. How would I obtain everything that is currently in the output stream and then continue with the execution of my Python program?