# csh stdin to Python stdin?

Tags: python, stdin, csh

How do you redirect the stdin of a csh script to the stdin of a python script?

I have a cgi script I'm writing in csh that runs on a Solaris machine. This csh script is a wrapper to a python script that reads from the stdin (I know, scripting in csh is bad but I'm forced to in this case).

Thanks for help! (And sorry for the n00b question!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

test.csh

```
#!/bin/env csh
python test.py
```

test.py (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python))

```
#!/bin/env python
import fileinput

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Hi. printing stdin"
    for line in fileinput.input():
        print line

    print "fin"
```

Then the stdin to `test.csh` is passed in to `test.py` [as Henning said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7234640/csh-stdin-to-python-stdin/7234676#7234676).

```
echo "this is stdin" | csh test.csh
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to do anything.
Commands (such that a Python script) that you start from a shell (such as csh) will inherit the shell's stdin (and stdout, stderr) *by default* unless you actively do something to prevent it.

Comment: So simple! I wish I could mark 2 answers as a solution. Thanks for the explanation!!!!

Comment: Oh well. I've made my quota for today anyway :-)