# Python as "perl -pe", execute Python command for every line in stdin

Tags: python, perl, sed, awk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python equivalent to perl -pe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842919/python-equivalent-to-perl-pe)

Is there a way to process each line of `stdin` with a given Python command without setting up things with boilerplate code?

With Perl, I can just do something like:

```
perl -pe '... command ...'
```

can I do the same with Python?

Note: something similar is possible with many other tools, e.g. sed, awk, etc...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python is not as convenient as Perl in this regard, but you can get close to Perl's `-p` flag using [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input), like this:

```
python -c 'for ln in __import__("fileinput").input(): print ln.rstrip()' files...
```

This will automatically open files in sequence like Perl does, or use the standard input if no files are provided. Replace `print` with any kind of processing. You might need multiple lines to do anything useful, but that is not a problem for most shells.

Note that `rstrip` is needed to avoid duplication of newlines from the source lines and those added by the `print` statement. If you're not printing the line, you don't need to call it.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input

Comment: I just thought it was helpful to have a link to the module that makes it work.

Comment: @JoshuaGoldberg Good point, I've now added the link to the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Try `-c` interpreter option:

```
python -c "print 'cool'"
```