# Can I use in python3 something like -n pipe-option in perl?

Tags: python, python-3.x, perl

If I look for a filename pattern in perl, you can do this simple:

```
ls -l | perl -n -e'if(/.*180205.*/){ print "$_\n"; }'
```

> `-n`
>   causes Perl to assume the following loop around your program, which makes it iterate over filename arguments somewhat like `sed -n` or `awk`:
>
> ```
> LINE:
>   while (<>) {
>       ...             # your program goes here
>   }
> ```

How can I code this in python3? (python3 --help shows not such option)

Comment: are you set on a command line or a python code would do?

Comment: You could considerably shorten that Perl program by doing `perl -n -E 'say if /180205/`

Comment: both interesting but commandline is much more important

Comment: @simbabque I now. But I want migrate from perl to python3!

Comment: Start by running `python3 --help` then. Or look at the man page for command line switches.

Comment: For anyone familiar with Python but not with Perl, you might want to describe what `-n` does exactly.

Comment: Actually, `perl --help` says that `-n` means _assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program_

Comment: Found this searching pypi: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/red/0.2.1

Comment: Why do you need either perl or python when you could do `ls -l *180205*`?

Comment: @JoshLee should work: not nice BUT useful

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842919/python-equivalent-to-perl-pe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38417743/are-there-anything-similar-to-perl-pe-option-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python oneliners with `python -c '...'` are extremely restricted, as the Python grammar assumes that each statement sits on its own line. You can combine some statements with a semicolon “`;`”, but some statements need to have their own line, notably compound statements like loops. If you want to write this on the command line, we have to express the loop over all lines as a list comprehension:

```
python3 -c 'import re, fileinput; [print(line, end="") for line in fileinput.input() if re.search("180205", line)]'
```

This is of course fairly unreadable, because Python is not well-suited for one-liners. Looping over the `fileinput.input()` is similar to Perl's `-n` option.

If you want to use Python, consider writing a script. This is much more readable:

```
import re, fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    if re.search("180205", line):
        print(line, end="")
```