# How to read and check stdin/stdout in python?

Tags: python

We have [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python) good answer for how to read stdin.

1. But I don't understand how do I run the python code so it will read from a file as `stdin`?
2. Is `print` is like `stdout`?

I ask it cause I saw this order in facebook demo puzzle:

> NOTE: You need to write the full code taking all inputs are from stdin
>   and outputs to stdout  If you are using "Java", the classname is
>   "Solution"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you are reading from `stdin`, you have three basic options:

- type stuff manually:

  ```
  $ python hello.py
  asfasfasf
  asfasfasfasfasf
  <TYPE CONTROL-D TO END STREAM>
  ```
- Using `<`:

  ```
  $ python hello.py < inputfile.txt
  ```
- Using the output from a previous command:

  ```
  $ cat inputfile.txt | grep oranges | python hello.py
  ```

All three of these will give you input via `stdin`.

---

After editing your question, you are no longer asking the same question. Here is the answer to your new questions:

1. You can do `sys.stdin = open('inputfile.txt')` to have the input file look like stdin. Make sure this is what you want. From your homework prompt, it sounds like my above solution is what you want.
2. `print` writes to stdout.

Comment: You missed `sys.stdin = fileobject`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to run code so that a *file* is read from stdin (instead of from an interactive terminal), then use redirection.

```
python program.py <input_file.txt
```

The `<` means the named file will be attached to stdin when the script is run. This syntax is the same on Windows, MacOS, and Unix-like platforms.

Comment: Thanks, I added a part about the stdout. can you answer this as well?

Comment: @ZoZo123 stdout is just `> out_file.txt`