# read and process stdin output of another console application

Tags: python

I want to manipulate the output of a console trace tool in a python script. So I want to read each line that the tool writes to stdout and maybe do something with that line and print it to the screen.

I have this script:

```
import sys

for l in sys.stdin:
    print l
```

and I start the trace tool like this:

```
qspy -c COM7 | my_script.py
```

the problem is when I hit enter the first time: nothing happens.  When I hit enter again, I see all the output that was created by the tool but it also quits (the trace-tool quits on any character).  What am I doing wrong?

i'm on windows.

---

EDIT:

I've tried all the suggestions, with little success:

first of all i created this little script to produce some output on stdout:

```
import time

while 1:
    time.sleep(1)
    print "test"
```

this does not work at all (no output):

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    print line,
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

this one also doesnt do anything:

```
import fileinput, sys

for line in fileinput.input():
    print line,
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

this one works, but only with the test-script, not with qspy:

```
import sys

for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, ''):
    print line,
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

i did call the scripts like this:

```
test.py | python -u my_script.py
```

and did also:

```
set PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the infinite while loop?

Comment: you are right, its useless. but also not part of the problem.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python

Comment: @Dill -- So you get the same behavior without the while statement?  If that's the case, you should edit and remove it.  Leaving it there is just confusing.

Comment: try `python -u test.py | python my_script.py` where iter...readline and .flush are used in my_script.

Answer (score 1):

Try to disable buffering:

```
$ qspy -c COM7 | python -u my_script.py
```

Also you could try to force reading line by line:

```
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline, '')
    print line,
```

Check wether qspy has an option that manages buffering.

You could also set `PYTHONUNBUFFERED` environment variable.

Comment: @Dill: if qspy is a Python script you could run it as: `python -u path/to/qspy` or set the environment variable and it should obey.

Comment: @Dill: if `qspy` uses stdio.h for IO and it doesn't override the buffering of its standard streams then you could try [`stdbuf`](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/stdbuf-man.html) to set line buffering of its stdout stream: `stdbuf -o L qspy -c COM7 | python ...`. Or run `qspy` from inside of `my_script.py` using `winpexpect` module.

Comment: comes time ill try this. what i did as a quick hack was to change the source of qspy to flush after each write to the logfile and open the logfile with python. i know that this isnt a good solution.