# Redirect bash output to python script

Tags: python, bash

I am using **zbarimg** to scan bar codes, I want to redirect the output to a python script. How can I redirect the output of the following command:

```
zbarimg code.png
```

to a python script, and what should be the script like?

I tried the following script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
s = raw_input()
print s
```

I made it an executable by issuing the following:

```
chmod +x in.py
```

Than I ran the following :

```
zbarimg code.png | in.py
```

I know it's wrong but I can't figure out anything else!

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python

Comment: What would an example output of `zbarimg code.png` look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the pipe operator `|` from the command is correct, actually.  Did it not work?

You might need to explicitly specify the path for the python script as in

```
zbarimg code.png | ./in.py
```

and as @dogbane says, reading from stdin like `sys.stdin.readlines()` is better than using `raw_input`

Answer (score 4):

Use [`sys.stdin`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.stdin) to read from stdin in your python script. For example:

```
import sys
data = sys.stdin.readlines()
```

Comment: Then should I write zbarimg code.png | in.py or should I do zbarimg code.png > in.py ?

Comment: you need to pipe into the python script: `zbarimg code.png | in.py`

Answer (score 2):

I had to invoke the python program command as 
`somecommand | python mypythonscript.py` instead of `somecommand | ./mypythonscript.py`. This worked for me. The latter produced errors.

My purpose: Sum up the durations of all mp3 files by piping output of `soxi -D *mp3`
into python: `soxi -D *mp3 | python sum_durations.py`

---

Details:

`soxi -D *mp3`produces:

```
122.473016
139.533016
128.456009
307.802993
...
```

sum_durations.py script:

```
import sys
import math
data = sys.stdin.readlines()
#print(data)
sum = 0.0
for line in data:
    #print(line)
    sum += float(line)

mins = math.floor(sum / 60)
secs = math.floor(sum) % 60

print("total duration: " + str(mins) + ":" + str(secs))
```