# How to print commands in Python?

Tags: python, debugging, io, stdout, stdin

I'm not in the programming area but I recently got interested in Python. I was writing some functions but for debugging I need to see what commands are running. For instance:

```
def foo():
    for i in xrange(0,5):
        a = 1 + i
```

Is it possible to make the interpreter output

```
>>> for i in xrange(0,5)
>>> a = 1 + 0
>>> a = 1 + 1
>>> a = 1 + 2
>>> a = 1 + 3
>>> a = 1 + 4
```

For

```
>>> foo()
```

Or at least write to a file what is happening? I did some scripting in the past and I remember that this was possible in DOS, using @ECHO ON or something. I did some reading and I feel like it's related to stdin and stdout in Python so I tried

```
import sys
def foo():
    for i in xrange(0,5):
        a = 1 + i
        sys.stdin.flush()
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

But I get nothing... I also tried

```
import sys
# foo()
sys.stdin.read()
sys.stdout.read()
```

and https://stackoverflow.com/a/3289051/2032568, but it just hangs. Sorry if this is not the right place for beginners. I couldn't find anything that answers my question.

Answer (score 4):

Have a look at the [trace-module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html)

```
python -m trace --count -C . somefile.py
```

output is placed in currebt directory:

```
$ cat somefile.trace
    1: def foo():
    6:     for i in xrange(5):
    5:         a = 1 + i

    1: foo()
```

> -c, --count
>    Produce a set of annotated listing files upon program completion that shows how many times each statement was executed

If using the `-t` option you get this:

```
$ python -m trace --count -t tr.py 
 --- modulename: tr, funcname: <module>
tr.py(1): def foo():
tr.py(5): foo()
 --- modulename: tr, funcname: foo
tr.py(2):     for i in xrange(5):
tr.py(3):         a = 1 + i
tr.py(2):     for i in xrange(5):
tr.py(3):         a = 1 + i
tr.py(2):     for i in xrange(5):
tr.py(3):         a = 1 + i
tr.py(2):     for i in xrange(5):
tr.py(3):         a = 1 + i
tr.py(2):     for i in xrange(5):
tr.py(3):         a = 1 + i
tr.py(2):     for i in xrange(5):
```

Answer (score 4):

To make the interpreter print out expression values during runtime you can use the [print](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#print) statement. Also take a note of Python's [string formatting facilities](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5082452/1025391).

Example:

```
for i in xrange(0,5):
    a = 1 + i
    # print the value of a:
    print "the current value of variable 'a':", a
```

There is no need to flush stdout explicitly, unless you want to enforce to print out lines without a terminating newline:

```
import sys
import time
for i in xrange(0,5):
    a = 1 + i
    # print the value of a:
    # the trailing comma prevents 'print' from adding a newline
    print "\rthe current value of variable 'a':", a, 
    sys.stdout.flush()
    # short pause for purposes of demonstration
    time.sleep(1)
# finally print a newline
print
```

---

To print each statement before it's executed have a look at the [trace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) module.

Example:

```
y = 0
for xi in range(3):
    y += xi
print y
```

The output:

```
$ python -m trace -t tt.py
 --- modulename: tt, funcname: <module>
tt.py(2): y = 0
tt.py(3): for xi in range(3):
tt.py(4):     y += xi
tt.py(3): for xi in range(3):
tt.py(4):     y += xi
tt.py(3): for xi in range(3):
tt.py(4):     y += xi
tt.py(3): for xi in range(3):
tt.py(5): print y
3
 --- modulename: trace, funcname: _unsettrace
trace.py(80):         sys.settrace(None)
```

---

What you are looking for in the first place, might also be a debugger, e.g. [pdb](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html). You get an interactive session, where you can step through the code, and have a look at the data interactively.

Example:

```
$ python -m pdb tt.py
> /home/moooeeeep/tt.py(2)<module>()
-> y = 0
(Pdb) n
> /home/moooeeeep/tt.py(3)<module>()
-> for xi in range(3):
(Pdb) n
> /home/moooeeeep/tt.py(4)<module>()
-> y += xi
(Pdb) n
> /home/moooeeeep/tt.py(3)<module>()
-> for xi in range(3):
(Pdb) n
> /home/moooeeeep/tt.py(4)<module>()
-> y += xi
(Pdb) print y, xi
0 1
(Pdb) 
...
```

Most Python IDEs (e.g., [PyDev](http://pydev.org/)) have nicely integrated debugging functionality. So my suggestion: go and get a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You mean something like this?

```
def foo():
         for i in xrange(0,5):
                 a = 1 + i
                 print "a = 1 + {0}".format(i)

>>> foo()
a = 1 + 0
a = 1 + 1
a = 1 + 2
a = 1 + 3
a = 1 + 4
```

Comment: Do you think the OP really wants to write explicit print statements?

Answer (score 0):

```
def foo():
    for i in xrange(0,5):
        a = 1 + i
        print a
```

i think this its what you are looking for, i hope this be usefull for you :)

edit:

i think i understood what you want:

```
def foo():
    for i in xrange(0,5):
        print "a = 1 + i"
```

Comment: Sure, but if I have, say: a = (x ** y) + (2 * b), I'd like to get a = (-1 ** 2) + (2 * 2), for x=-1, y=2, b=2. Not only the result, which would be 4.

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you what to achieve here and I checked that link: it hangs for me too, and only repeats inputted text in the Terminal. Unfortunately I don't know how to print out the script as you've asked: for debugging, I'd advise just using simple print commands to work out which section is being executed.

```
def foo():
    for i in xrange(0,5):
        a = 1 + i, print "line is being executed where i = %i " % i
```

Then just read the printed text output to see what the program is doing.
Hope this helps.