# Shell pipe working asynchronously

Tags: python, shell, stdout, stdin

I thought each processes pipe connected work asynchronously but it doesn't.

a.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import time
for line in sys.stdin:
    time.sleep(2)
    sys.stdout.write(line.upper())
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

and b.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    sys.stdout.write(line.capitalize())
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

and test.txt

```
hello
world
python
```

Following code show each lines one by one by 2 seconds.

```
$ ./a.py < test.txt
HELLO
WORLD
PYTHON
```

But following code show entirely one time.

```
$ ./a.py < test.txt | ./b.py
Hello
World
Python
```

It looks that shell pipe is working synchronously. How can I do asynchronously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the code is that, although the expression...

```
for line in sys.stdin:
    # ...
```

...is treating `sys.stdin` as an iterator, it doesn't seem to yield any values until `sys.stdin` hits EOF, much like the behavior of `sys.stdin.readlines()`.

For the first case, it hits EOF almost immediately, but in the second case, it has to wait for `a.py` to terminate, which takes 6 seconds.

You'll have to rewrite the code for `b.py` like this...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
while 1:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    sys.stdout.write(line.capitalize())
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

...using `readline()` to get the call to return as soon as it has a whole line, rather than waiting for EOF.

You should probably also make a similar change to `a.py` in case you want to pipe input from something other than a text file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found similar thread in http://stackoverflow.com/a/7608205/395425 In python2.7 "for" statement is waiting the EOF, but python3.3 doesn't wait.

Comment: I found later, python 2.x "for line in sys.stdin" does not wait to EOF. It seems to be buffering.

Answer (score 0):

You could use threads, but I don't know if this fits your likings. ;)

Ps: thread in python are very easy, I can provide an example, if you need.