# How to pass options or parameters in python script within standard input?

Tags: python, command-line

my python script is using stdin

usage is `grep "asda" myfile" | python myscript.py`

I use it in this way

```
lines = []
for line in fileinput.input():
    lines.append(line)
```

it works ok.

but now I need to pass parameters like `grep "asda" myfile" | python myscript.py -o out`

i tried to use fileinput.input(sys.stdin) for taking lines from stdin only, but it fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parser.py", line 29, in <module>
    for line in fileinput.input(sys.stdin):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 253, in next
    line = self.readline()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/fileinput.py", line 345, in readline
    self._file = open(self._filename, self._mode)
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '<Operation adaptorMethod="search" adaptorName="Search" status="Success" timeCreated="2013-10-15T02:43:33.728-0700" timeLastUpdated="2013-10-15T02:43:33.728-0700"/>\n'
```

output of grep contains such lines

```
 <Operation adaptorMethod="search" adaptorName="Search" status="Success" timeCreated="2013-10-15T02:43:33.728-0700" timeLastUpdated="2013-10-15T02:43:33.728-0700"/>
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you read from stdin in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python)

Comment: On top of that, use [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) to parse the arguments separately?

Answer (score 0):

You need `sys.argv`, which will give you the values passed to your script on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

```
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Stdin could be handled by sys.stdin.readlines() instead of for line in fileinput.input()