# How do I use the < > commands in my program?

Tags: python, shell, command-line

I have written a program that calculates the counts of each word in an input file. At the moment I am getting the filename using sys.argv[1], but I am actually supposed to be using

```
python word_counts.py < homer.txt > homer.test
```

I think homer.txt is the input file that is directed to my python script, while homer.test is the file that the output of my script is written to.

How do I make these work in my program?

Comment: These are OS-level features.  Just use stdin and stdout.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python

Answer (score 3):

The information in homer.txt is provided on standard-in.  In python, that is a file handle called `sys.stdin`:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin: # reads from homer.txt
    # process line
    print(output) # writes to homer.test
```

`homer.test` is collecting data from standard-out.  In python, the print statement writes to stdout by default.  If you want to treat it explicitly as a file handle, you can use `sys.stdout`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `sys.stdin` to read from homer.txt and `sys.stdout` (or `print`) to write to homer.test.