# Unix: output of one script file as input to another script

Tags: python, unix, redirect

I run some python files in Linux through command line and I want the out-put of one file to be the input to another..

Eg.
in the command line

```
python  file1.python file1.txt
```

display some characters.....

and I want these characters to be used to another command
So I want something like

```
python file2.python   characters_from_previous_output file2.txt
```

I know that this is wrong but lets say

```
python file2.python   (python file1.python file1.txt ) file2.txt
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you read from stdin in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python)

Comment: I do not feel that they are the same..

Comment: Why do you need `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` as arguments for these scripts execution? What are they used for? Are you reading from them or writing to them?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make `file2.python` to accept standard input instead of file input
2. Run `python file1.python file1.txt | python file2.python file2.txt`

Comment: I get "IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe" .. I made a mistake before the first python command is like  python file1.py a < b  and the second one is like python file2.python previous_output c