# python only recognizes first line of my input

Tags: python, input

With this code:

```
A = raw_input("Please input text here")
print A
print len(A)
```

---

For the `input`, when I copy and paste from notepad, it only recognizes the first line of the following:

```
Cars are fast
Motorcycles are faster
Planes are even faster
```

---

Therefore, `print A` will `print` 'Cars are fast' and `print len(A)` with `print 13`, which is the length of 'Cars are fast'.

How can I get Python to recognize the remaining lines of my `input`?

Thank you.

Comment: Calling the function on a loop?

Comment: maybe I'm being dense but I can't figure out how to loop over multiple lines of input

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[raw_input](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#raw_input) will read one line of input only.

See answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python) for a general overview of getting input from the command line.

If you want to use raw_input then a loop will read all your lines but you will need a way to break out, something like this.

```
while True:
    A = raw_input("Please input text here (Q to quit)")
    if len(A) == 1 and A[0].lower() == "q":
        break
    print A
    print len(A)
```

To collate multiple lines do something like this

```
data = []
while True:
    A = raw_input("Please input text here (Q to quit)")
    if len(A) == 1 and A[0].lower() == "q":
        break
    data.append(A)

print data
for A in data:
    print len(A)
```

Remember to enter a newline after pasting. Also, the raw_input prompt messages may not display correctly.

You could go crazy and manage the prompt. Expecting a zero length input means the user is trying to quit.

```
data = []
prompt = "Please input text (Q to quit):\n"
while True:
    if data:
        A = raw_input()
    else:
        A = raw_input(prompt)    
    while len(A) == 0:
        A = raw_input(prompt)
    if len(A) == 1 and A[0].lower() == "q":
        break        
    data.append(A)

for A in data:
    print "%s - %i" % (A, len(A))
```

Comment: is there a different input function that will read multiple lines?

Comment: No, but you can write your own in the suggested form.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to reply. I might be wrong but the way that you're suggesting I do it would require me to manually enter each line of text wouldn't it? What I would like to do is input any number of lines, and then have python return a list of strings so that list[0] would be the first line, list[1] would be the second line, etc.

Comment: You can copy and paste multiple lines at once and the programme will read each line in turn. You might want to collect all the data into a list before processing it.

Comment: A small deviation from this could be using '' (a blank string) as a sentinel instead of 'q', it all depends upon your requirement. But AFAIK Python doesn't have a inbuilt multi line read.

Comment: Of course @JagjeetSinghThukral is correct, the 'Q' is optional and depends on what you need.

Answer (score 0):

There is `sys.stdin` object that has `read` method. By default method reads till end of file.

```
>>> import sys
>>> file_content = sys.stdin.read() # press CTRL+D to close stdin
```

You can read more about this method using:

```
>>> help(sys.stdin.read)
```

Or

```
>>> help(sys.read)
```