# Run a django shell in batch file with script

Tags: python, django, django-shell

I wanna ask how to make a "python manage.py shell" and add a "from myapp.model import Contact c = Contact.objects.all().count() print c". Is this possible in a batch file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
echo "from myapp.model import Contact; c = Contact.objects.all().count(); print c" | python manage.py shell
```

Or this [How do you read from stdin in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python)

Comment: i tried it,it just display the command prompt and then closed.