# Python program to send the input of text file to youtube search api?

Tags: python, python-2.7, youtube, pyscripter

I have a text file file1.txt that contains a list of keywords.

```
python
dictionary
list
process
program
```

and so on.

I'm using the official python youtube api to search for these keywords; which at present I'm doing manually. How to automate this such that the program can search for these keywords one after another automatically.

```
from apiclient.discovery import build
from apiclient.errors import HttpError
from oauth2client.tools import argparser
DEVELOPER_KEY = "BIzaSyCwzkEAWUFXvWq0u1hybEK3ZdlQw-YRg2w"
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = "youtube"
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = "v3"

def youtube_search(options):
  youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION,
    developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

# Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified query term.
search_response = youtube.search().list(
  q=options.q,
  part="id,snippet",
  maxResults=options.max_results
).execute()
videos = []
for search_result in search_response.get("items", []):
  if search_result["id"]["kind"] == "youtube#video":
    videos.append("%s (%s)" % (search_result["snippet"]["title"],
                             search_result["id"]["videoId"]))
print "Videos:\n", "\n".join(videos), "\n"
keyword=raw_input("Enter the keyword you want to search video's for:")

if __name__ == "__main__":
  argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default=keyword)
  argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=5)
  args = argparser.parse_args()

 try:
   youtube_search(args)
 except HttpError, e:
   print "An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s" % (e.resp.status, e.content)
```

Edit 1:
I did as you asked.

```
words = open('D:\keywordq.txt', 'r').read().split("\n")
for w in words:
  #keyword=raw_input("Enter the keyword you want to search video's for:")
  if __name__ == "__main__":
    argparser.add_argument("--q", help="Search term", default=w)
    argparser.add_argument("--max-results", help="Max results", default=5)
    args = argparser.parse_args()
```

Now in the output i get 5 blank lines instead of results.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read in the text using (assuming the words in your file are newline delimited) 
`words = open(FILENAME, 'r').read().split('\n')`? Then you can iterate through this list using a for loop `for w in words:` and just repeat your keyword search process there.

If you want to allow either specifying a file OR manually entering words, just read from the standard input (see [How do you read from stdin in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python))

Comment: I tried using **read.split('\n')**, it worked the first time but then started getting Message **AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'split'**

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the example.  There should be parens after read. Its fixed now, and should work.

Comment: did you try printing each word in the loop to ensure that much is working as expected?

Comment: I tried printing each word, but only first one will be printed.