# What does "<<<" mean on a bash command line? And where is it documented?

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, operators, pipe

What does `<<<` mean in this command line?

```
bc <<< "1 + 1"
```

It doesn't seem to a combination of `<` and `<<`, and I can't find documentation for it. It seems to behave just like

```
echo "1 + 1" | bc
```

Also works in `ksh`, but not in `sh`.

Comment: Search `Here Strings` in `man bash`

Comment: @anubhava You don't even need to know what they are called; it's sufficient to search for `<<<` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It introduces a here string, documented near the end of the section on input and output redirections. A here string is just a one-word here document:

```
bc <<< "1 + 1"
```

is equivalent to

```
bc <<EOF
1 + 1
EOF
```

Comment: Here String is helpful if you want to avoid quotation marks, e.g. `bc<<<1+2` in contrast to `echo "1+2"|bc` that needs quotation either single or double.

Comment: *Mostly*, although there were some bugs regarding word splitting and here strings that weren't fixed until versions 4.2 and 4.4, so you have to be aware of what version of `bash` you are using. I still quote them just to be safe, even in 5.x.

Comment: (At least in this answer, I quoted the here string to stay as close as possible to the here document, which behaves like a double-quoted string when no part of the delimiter is escaped.)

Answer (score 2):

That is the here string operator. See [here string operator document.](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
man ksh
```

You can perform a search in a manual by typing / (slash) follow by what you search, like with [less](http://ss64.com/bash/less.html) program.