# What's the difference between stdin and sys.argv in python?

Tags: python

I was docked points in a coding challenge that specified that I needed to read from STDIN. This was my input method:

```
def __init__(self, input):
    self._dictionary = {}
    with open(input, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        for row in reader:
          if self._dictionary.__contains__(row[0]):
            self._dictionary[row[0]].append(row[1])
          else:
            self._dictionary.update({row[0]: row[1].split()})
```

and at the end of the script

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    script = Script(sys.argv[1])
    for line in script.output_method():
      print line
```

Was I wrong to use sys.argv in a challenge that asked to read from stdin? What's the difference? What should I have done to satisfy the requirements?

Comment: `STDIN` - wherefrom you will take the input (test cases) for your program. `sys.argv` - the arguments provided to program when running it.

Comment: Yeah, I get that. But what about the above script does not satisfy "script must read from STDIN"?

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python There are multiple answers in there that come under stdin

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are not the same:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.argv == sys.stdin
False
```

*sys.argv*

- The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.

*sys.stdin*
sys.stdout
sys.stderr

- File objects corresponding to the interpreter’s standard input, output and error streams. stdin is used for all interpreter input except for scripts but including calls to input() and raw_input().

As @Vivek Rai mentioned in the comments, you can use `sys.stdin.readlines()` to read from standard in.  Also, [`fileinput`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html), is available to you, which seems to do exactly what you want.

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.input():
    process(line)
```

> This iterates over the lines of all files listed in sys.argv[1:],
>   defaulting to sys.stdin if the list is empty. If a filename is '-', it
>   is also replaced by sys.stdin. To specify an alternative list of
>   filenames, pass it as the first argument to input(). A single file
>   name is also allowed.

Comment: What should I have done to satisfy the requirements?

Comment: @BarFooBar: You should have read from `stdin` instead of from a user-specified file.

Comment: @BarFooBar Simply do, `sys.stdin.readlines()` to read all lines from the input.

Comment: @BarFooBar instead of passing a string as the argument, pass a file object. If sys.argv includes a filename, open and pass that; otherwise pass sys.stdin.

I strongly believe in not hard-coding `stdin` except at the highest level in `main`