# How to Accept Command Line Arguments With Python Using <

Tags: python, shell, terminal

Is it possible to run a python script and feed in a file as an argument using `<`?  For example, my script works as intended using the following command `python scriptname.py input.txt` and the following code `stuffFile = open(sys.argv[1], 'r')`.

However, what I'm looking to do, if possible, is use this command line syntax: `python scriptname.py < input.txt`.  Right now, running that command gives me only one argument, so I likely have to adjust my code in my script, but am not sure exactly how.

I have an automated system processing this command, so it needs to be exact.  If that's possible with a Python script, I'd greatly appreciate some help!

Comment: Yup, this seems to address it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`< file` is handled by the shell: the file doesn't get passed as an argument. Instead it becomes the standard input of your program, i.e., `sys.stdin`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sys module's stdin attribute as a file like object.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the < operator in a shell you are actually opening the file and adding its contents to your scripts stdin
However there is is a python module that can do both. It's called fileinput. 
https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html
It was shown in this post
[How do you read from stdin in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python)