# Read inputfile as csv in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I want to read a csv file from STDIN and operate on it.

The following is the code for reading the csv file and doing the operation needed. This works fine. But I want to take the input from STDIN.

```
import csv
with open('hospital_data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    myDict = {}

    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    for row in csvreader:
        if row[6] not in myDict.keys():
            #print 'Zipcode: ' + row[6] + ' Hospital code: ' + row[1]
            myDict[row[6]] = 1
        elif row[6] in myDict.keys():
            #print 'value in row '+ str(myDict[row[6]])
            myDict[row[6]] += 1
```

Is there a way in Python to read the file from STDIN as a csv file ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`csv.reader` will take anything that yields lines, so you can use any of the methods shown at this answer to get lines from stdin:
[How do you read from stdin in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python)

I'm partial to `fileinput` myself due to its flexibility. EG:

```
import csv
import fileinput

myDict = {}
csvreader = csv.reader(fileinput.input(mode='rb'), delimiter=',')
```

But this works too:

```
import csv
import sys

myDict = {}
csvreader = csv.reader(sys.stdin, delimiter=',')
```

If you do that, you'll want to run with the `-u` command line argument to make stream binary, if that makes a difference on your platform:
https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-u

In either case you'll need to use control-D to mark the end of the input.

Note that the correct way to check if a key is in a dict is `if row[6] in myDict` rather than checking `keys`. And in fact if you just want a default value when the key is not present, use `get`:

```
for row in csvreader:
    myDict[row[6]] = myDict.get(row[6], 0) + 1
```

Or look into `collections.Counter`, since you're on 2.7:

```
myDict = collections.Counter(row[6] for row in csvreader)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use sys.stdin, it's file-like object.

```py
import sys
import csv

data = sys.stdin.readlines()
csvreader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',')
for row in csvreader:
    print row
```