# print variable and string

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using Python 3 and I can't seem to figure out how to print something from an input and the thing that they input.

```
var = input("Enter something: ")
print("you entered")
```

I have something along these lines, and I need the print function to print "you entered" and what they input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you read from stdin in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is this:

```
var = input('Enter something:')
    print("You entered: %s") % (var)
```

This could also be done in one line:

```
print ("You entered: %s"%input('Enter something:'))
```

Comment: This does not work. I assume you meant to type `print("You entered ", var)`.

Comment: Corrected it. I don't use python3 myself. @KSFT

Answer (score 0):

What you input is stored in var, you need to %var to print what you input.

```
var = input('Enter something:')
print("You entered %s"%var)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your problem is to do this.

Here is what you are doing:

```
var = input("Enter something: ")
print("you entered")
```

Here is what you want to do:

```
var = input("Enter something:")
print("You Entered: %s") % (var)
```

You can also try this:

```
var = input("Enter something:")
print("You Entered:", var)
```

Or this:

```
print ("You entered: %s"%input('Enter something:'))
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

definitely answer should be

```
var = input('Enter something:')
print("You entered %s"%var)
```

you should print the var to see it as a out put