# How to compose Python exe programs using pipes?

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file, command-line, pipe

Python newbie here.

1. I created a Python program, `msg.py`, which outputs a message (Hello, World).
2. I created a Python program, `id.py`, which reads input and outputs it.
3. Using `py2exe` I created an executable of each of them: `msg.exe` and `id.exe`
4. I created a DOS batch file, set `PATH` to the `dist` folder of `msg.exe` and the `dist` folder of `id.exe`.
5. I then added this to the DOS batch file:

   msg | id

When I ran the batch file I got this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "id.py", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I surmised that the pipe symbol is not feeding the output of `msg.exe` to the input of `id.exe`. Is that correct?

6. So then I placed this in the batch file:

   id < msg

When I ran the batch file I got this error message:

```
Access is denied.
```

I really want step `5` to work. That is, I really want to be able to compose programs using the pipe symbol, like so:

```
A | B | C | ...
```

Ideally `A`, `B`, `C`, ... could be executables written in various languages, such as `Python`, `C`, etc.

How do I get this to work?

Below are the details of what I did. I am running on Windows 7.

Here is `msg.py`

```
import stdio

stdio.writeln('Hello, World')
```

Here is `id.py`

```
import sys
import stdio

msg = sys.argv[1]
stdio.writeln(msg)
```

Here is my DOS batch file:

```
@echo OFF

set PATH=%PATH%;msg/dist;id/dist

msg | id
```

Comment: Your surmising is incorrect. The traceback is telling you that there is an error with `sys.argv[1]`. When you use py2exe and invoke it that way, there is only `sys.argv[0]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.argv` is for command line parameters (id.py a b c).

To read from a pipe, you need to use `sys.stdin.read()` in id.py.

Edit: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7608205/478656

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works - yay! I am on my way! (Apparently, "msg" is the name of a DOS command, so I had to change from msg.py to mesg.py)