# Redirect gunzip output to python script

Tags: python, gunzip

I want to `gunzip` a series of files and then redirect the output to my python script. The python script gets one argument as the input. I wrote the following command:

```
for i in $(ls test5/*/*gz); do gunzip -c $i | python script.py ; done
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./fqtofa.py", line 7, in <module>
    inFile = sys.argv[1]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I wonder why it can't read from the `gunzip` output.

Comment: You're reading input from stdin, checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.argv` is for command-line arguments. You're not passing any of those, you're piping it in via stdin. So you need to read from `sys.stdin`.