# Read in text from STDIN Python

Tags: python, stdin, numeric

I'm wondering how to read this in from STDIN and store it into into two numeric variables. Thank you

```
10
20
```

-Rik

Comment: it is unclear of what you are asking ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you read from stdin in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python2.7+:

```
x=int(raw_input()) #Terminal will stall to allow user to input the first number
y=int(raw_input()) #This will wait for the second number to be inputted
```

In python3:

```
x=int(input()) #Terminal will stall to allow user to input the first number
y=int(input()) #This will wait for the second number to be inputted
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great