# Immediately output user input to console

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

The following code works great for Python 3. It immediately outputs the user input to the console

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print (line)
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work for Python 2.7 and 2.6 (yes, i do change the print command) - it just wouldn't output my lines

Am i making some stupid mistake, or is there another way to make it work for lower versions of Python?

Comment: related Python 2 bug ["for line in file" doesn't work for pipes](http://bugs.python.org/issue3907)

Comment: unrelated: you want `print(line, end='')` on Python 3 here (`line` includes the trailing newline unless it is EOF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `iter` and `sys.stdin.readline` to get the output straight away similar to the behaviour in python3:

```
import sys
for line in iter(sys.stdin.readline,""):
    print(line)
```

The `""` is a sentinel value which will break our loop when EOF is reached or you enter CTRL-D on unix or CTRL-Z on windows.

Answer (score 2):

You can make this nicer for the user on Unix-like systems by importing [readline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html), which gives you line editing capabilities, including history. But you have to use `raw_input()` (or `input()` on Python 3), rather than `sys.stdin.readline()`.

```
import readline

while True:
    try:
        print raw_input()
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> to terminate the program cleanly via EOF.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python).

```
import sys

while 1:
    try:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
    except KeyboardInterrupt: # Ctrl+C
        break
    if not line: # EOF
        break
    print line, # avoid adding newlines (comma: softspace hack)
```

A bit messed up it is, innit? :)

Comment: That is messed up. You need to just iterate over readline. See Pedraic's answer.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: at the time of the posting of this answer, @ Padraic Cunningham's answer was wrong (it read until an empty line instead of EOF). Even today, the answers are not equivalent: consider what happens on `Ctrl+C` and this answer doesn't print unnecessary empty lines between each input line (`print line,` vs. `print line`)