# Pass a file list from PowerShell to Python script via stdin

Tags: windows, powershell, python-3.x

I'd like to create a Python script that I can pipe file names into, so it can be used like this:

```
ls *.csv | python .\myscript.py
```

I know I can read the standard input using `fileinput` or `sys.stdin`, but since the output is in a formatted table:

```
    Directory: C:\path\to\csv


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----       15.02.2016     10:18           4755 data_1.csv
-a----       15.02.2016     10:18            522 data_2.csv
```

I'd have to parse it.

Since this seems to be a common pattern, I expect there's a standard solution. I'd like to avoid writing my own if I can, but I haven't been able to find any.

(In case it's important, I'm running it in PowerShell on Windows 10.)

**Edit:** I'm asking whether there's some library or pattern I'm missing, for this specific (and seemingly quite common) scenario of piping file paths to a script. I'd like to avoid writing parsing code if it isn't necessary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you read from stdin in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python)

Comment: I'd argue against this being a duplicate of that question. I'm asking whether there's some library or pattern I'm missing, for this specific (and seemingly quite common) scenario.

Comment: You probably want to find a way to get only the file names: solve this from PowerShell, and not from Python where you would get a file per line.

Comment: Does "ls *.csv | fl" displays only each filename without the metadata? I don't have a Windows system nearby to try this.

Comment: is there any issue with using `myscript *.csv` instead? (`filenames = sys.argv[1:]`)

Comment: What do you want to pass to Python? Just file name: `ls *.csv | % FullName | python .\myscript.py`?