# How can I allow multiple lines of user input in python?

Tags: python, text

I'm trying to create a *very* simple text editor for an MS-DOS style program I'm making using python. My problem comes when I try to create paragraphs. The way I made it, pressing `Enter` tells it to save the input. I understand what I did wrong, but how can I fix it and how could I break the input? So far I have this:

```
def textwriter():
    print("")
    print("Start typing to begin.")
    textwriterCommand = input(" ")
    saveAs = input("Save file as: ")
    with open(saveAs, 'w') as f:
        f.write(textwriterCommand)
```

Comment: This might be what you want but I'm not sure how you break the input then. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3289051/5889975

Comment: If you use the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python/3289051#3289051) that @steven linked to, you can watch for two blank lines (lines consisting of a newline only) in a row — perhaps by setting a flag — to break out of the loop. This is commonly how I've seen it handled.

Comment: I've updated my answer so the examples actually work in the way one would expect, which should be more helpful -- specifically, the second example works perfectly, with newlines

Comment: This isn't well specified. What is the **rule that tells you** when the input is done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@zamuz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35517023/4532996) is good, and good for simple things like this, but when your code gets more complex, I prefer to use something like [input_constrain](https://github.com/catb0t/input_constrain), which actually tests each keypress to decide what to do next. (Full disclosure: I wrote this.)

For example, to read input until the user presses `|` (vertical bar):

```
from input_constrain import until

def textwriter():
    print("")
    print("Start typing to begin.")
    textwriterCommand = until("|")
    saveAs = input("Save file as: ")
    with open(saveAs, 'w') as f:
        f.write(textwriterCommand)
```

Or, to read input until <kbd>CTRL - C</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL - D</kbd> (or any other unprintable control char):

```
from input_constrain import until_not
from string import printable as ALLOWED_CHARS

def textwriter():
    print("")
    print("Start typing to begin.")
    textwriterCommand = until_not(ALLOWED_CHARS, count=5000, raw=True)
    saveAs = input("Save file as: ")
    with open(saveAs, 'w') as f:
        f.write(textwriterCommand)
```

This uses an optional `count` parameter, which will stop reading after exactly this many keypresses. `raw=True` is important because otherwise, <kbd>CTRL - C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL - D</kbd> will throw exceptions. By using `raw`, we can break and continue the task at hand.

---

**Important**: You need commit [06e4bf3e72e23c9700734769e42d2b7fe029a2c1](https://github.com/catb0t/input_constrain/commit/06e4bf3e72e23c9700734769e42d2b7fe029a2c1) because it contains fixes but no breaking changes

Answer (score 2):

Assign some other EOF sequence, for instance:

```
EOF_SEQ = 'EOF'

def textwriter():
    print("")
    print("Start typing to begin.")
    buffer = ''
    while EOF_SEQ not in buffer:
        buffer += raw_input(" ") + '\n'
    saveAs = raw_input("Save file as: ")
    with open(saveAs, 'w') as f:
        f.write(buffer)
```

Comment: Change `raw_input` to `input`; OP's using Py3