# can someone confirm that this dosen't work on python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

it's supposed to add a and b after you type them , example is `2` ,`5` ,it should `return 7`.

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.read()
tokens = input.split()
a = int(tokens[0])
b = int(tokens[1])
print(a + b)
```

But, when i run it, it's just stuck and it doesn't do anything , i type the numbers and it doesn't do anything.

Is it because i'm using the 3.5 version?

Comment: why you are not using `input` ?

Comment: It is going to read from `stdin` until you press Ctrl+D.

Comment: its from a course in coursera , they want you to use sys.stdin

Comment: Read this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python

Comment: weird Ctrl+D seems to work , i have no idea why

Comment: Ctrl+D is `EOF` (end of file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `sys.stdin.read()` will read until the stream ends (you can press Ctrl-D to send the Signal)
use `input()`.
(Also, don't use input, or any other keywords or standard methods as a variable name.)