# powershell wildcards in passing filenames as argument(s)

Tags: powershell, wildcard

I am running `Python 3` on a Windows machine using `PowerShell`. I am trying to execute a Python file and then pass a number of files (file1.html, file2.html, etc.) as arguments using a wildcard character. I can get this to work, performing a couple of steps like below:

```
PS $files = Get-Item .\file*.html

PS python mypythonfile.py $files
```

My question is can this be done without having to use `Get-Item` and assigning the results to a variable? I tried running the same file like this `python mypythonfile.py .\file*.html` but this results in an error from the Python interpreter because PowerShell doesn't parse out the wildcard and passes the string with the wildcard.

Comment: I don't think this actually has anything to do with Python.

Comment: @Ajean - I probably shouldn't have added a Python tag, I'm new to this and only thought it might help with the context of the question. I agree, it's a PowerShell question, not Python.

Comment: No problem, I went ahead and removed it - the rest of the question is perfectly fine (although me not being a Powershell person I can't answer it...).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It seems that you are in the interactive console. You do not need to assign the results of get-item to a variable, if that is all you are trying to achieve. Try this:

```
python mypythonfile.py (get-item .\file*.html)
```

Although this will work, you should really be passing Python the name of the file properly by using .FullName property of the resulting objects generated by get-item:

```
python mypythonfile.py (get-item .\file*.html).FullName
```

Comment: Note that the second suggestion requires PowerShell v3 or newer unless the pattern expands to a single file.

Answer (score 9):

While Windows shells (namely PowerShell and CMD) do support [glob patterns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), they don't expand the patterns themselves (unlike Unix shells). Instead commands that are supposed to support globbing must implement wildcard expansion themselves.

Python provides the [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) module for that:

```python
import sys
import glob

for arg in glob.glob(sys.args[1]):
    print(arg)
```

That allows your script to handle arguments with wildcards when called e.g. like this:

```bsh
python script.py .\file*.html
```

Otherwise you need to use a PowerShell cmdlet that expands wildcard patterns for you and returns a list of paths, e.g. `Get-ChildItem`. Either collect the list in a variable:

```bsh
$files = Get-ChildItem .\file*.html | Select-Object -Expand FullName
python script.py $files
```

or run the PowerShell statement in an [expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators):

```bsh
python script.py (Get-ChildItem .\file*.html | Select-Object -Expand FullName)
```

Or you could have your Python script [read from `stdin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1454400/1630171):

```python
import fileinput

for line in fileinput.input():
    print(line.replace('\n',''))
```

and pipe the file list into your script:

```bsh
Get-ChildItem .\file*.html | Select-Object -Expand FullName | python script.py
```

Answer (score 1):

Do a `$files | get-Member` to see that `Get-Item` doesn't return a string but a `System.IO.FileInfo` object holding several entries.
If there are no spaces in the file names this could do:

```
 $files = (Get-Item .\file*.html) -join(' ')
```

Otherwise

```
$files =  '"'+((Get-Item .\file*.html) -join('" "'))+'"'
```