# How to take user input in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, input, append

```
import numpy

my_array = numpy.array([])
a=int(input("Size of array:"))
for i in range(a):
    x=float(input("Element:"))
    numpy.append(x)

print(numpy.floor(my_array))
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I am trying to solve hackerrank.com question.Here is the link https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/floor-ceil-and-rint/forum  .I have found a way to input but the output format is wrong.check my code. import numpy as np
A = np.array(input().split(' '),float)
print(np.floor(A))
print(np.ceil(A))
print(np.rint(A))

Comment: Please update your post with a proper question/problem and code formatting, so that others may benefit from reading it.

Comment: The question asks how can one read an input from the user to enter the "size of the array" and other parameters.  This has been asked and answered before here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38670261/53720. Please if you have other problems be more specific about what sort of error you are dealing with.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you read from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin)

Answer (score 5):

```
n, m = map(int, input().split()) # taking number of rows and column
array = numpy.array([input().strip().split() for _ in range(n)], int)
```

Answer (score 3):

Please try this

```
from numpy import *
arr = array([])
n = int(input("Enter the number of values you want:  "))

for i in range(n):
    v = input("Element:  ")
    arr = append(arr, v)
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

`numpy.append` does not work like this, the array is missing to append to.

Better, build a normal list and convert it to a numpy array afterwards:

```
import numpy

my_array = []
a = int(input("Size of array:"))
for i in range(a):
    my_array.append(float(input("Element:")))
my_array = numpy.array(my_array)
print(numpy.floor(my_array))
```

Answer (score 2):

You take input as list and then put it into a numpy array.

```
import numpy
op= list(map(int,input().split()))
op = numpy.asarray(op)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using List Comprehension

```
a=int(input()
b=[int(j) for j in input().split()]
print(np.array(b))
```

Comment: Have you missed the round bracket? a=int(input() ?

Comment: oh yes.. silly mistakes,

Answer (score 0):

You can initialise a list of length 'a' and then can replace its element  with input elements:

```
import numpy
a=int(input("Size of array:"))

my_array = numpy.empty(a)
for i in range(len(my_array)):
    x=float(input("Element:"))
    my_array[i]=x
print(numpy.floor(my_array))
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this

```
from numpy import *
n=int(input("Enter Size of array"))
arr=zeros(n,dtype=int)
for i in range(n):
   x=int(input("Enter the value"))
   arr[i]=x
print(arr)
```