# Passing command line arguments in python - is there more than one standard input?

Tags: python

So I'm working on something right now and I'm trying to be able to run it in the command line. I was able to run my python file given this command "python ./pythonprogram.py arg1"

However,

"python ./pythonprogram.py < arg1"

should apparently work as well. E.g. [this article](https://www.codecademy.com/articles/command-line-commands) says that the "symbol" indicates that arg1 is suppose to be inputted into the program on the left. Am i missing something? Is Python an exception and can arguments only be passed via a space? Thank you!

Comment: `< arg` does not pass a command line argument. It sends the content of the file `arg1` to the program's stdin. This is really more of a SuperUser question than a SO question.

Answer (score 2):

They do different things.

This:

```
python ./pythonprogram.py arg1
```

means "run my program and pass the string `arg1` as an argument"

This:

```
python ./pythonprogram.py < arg1
```

means "read the file `arg1` and pass its content to stdin for my program".

See also [How do you read from stdin in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python)

Comment: So for the former, I know that I'll have to import sys and put sys.argv to pass arg1 it...how do I do the latter, assuming that arg1 turns out to be a text file? When i enter "python ./pythonprogram.py < arg1" on my commandline I get an error. Thank you by the way!

Comment: @bea [How do you read from stdin in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin-in-python)