# In python, what is a functional, and memory efficient way to read standard in, line by line?

Tags: python, functional-programming

I have this https://stackoverflow.com/a/1450396/1810962 answer from another post which almost achieves it:

```python
import sys
data = sys.stdin.readlines()
preProcessed = map(lambda line: line.rstrip(), data)
```

I can now operate on the lines in `data` in a functional way by applying filter, map, etc. However, it loads the entire standard in into memory. Is there a lazy way to build a stream of lines?

Comment: what is wrong with `input`

Comment: `sys.stdin` already *is* a lazy iterator of the lines in the file. `len(sys.stdin)` doesn't work, but something more explicit like `sum(1 for x in sys.stdin)` would. `len` specifically requires something more concrete than an arbitrary iterator.

Comment: let me update. i don't care about the len(data) part. i don't want to compute the length. I want to operate against a stream of lines

Comment: I understand that sys.stdin is lazy, but sys.stdin.readlines() is not

Comment: what is `input` ?

Comment: Never mind `input()`, it's how you read _one_ line from stdin. I don't see how it is relevant here.

Comment: Not sure why you're so keen on doing something inherently effectful in a 'functional' way....

Comment: @JaredSmith: Not sure why you think streaming from standard in is inherently effectful.

Comment: @joseph because reading from stdin *is* a side-effect. There's no referential transparency: you could get anything from stdin. Ditto for any other form of I/O. Which is why in e.g. haskell you have to wrap it in the IO monad. Your question conceptually doesn't quite meet at the seems for me.

Comment: @JaredSmith: Suppose I want to compute the sum of the numbers in standard in. Even though standard in has referential transparency, it does not prevent me from filtering non-number lines, and compute the sum on the remaining lines using reduce.

Comment: @joseph you can certainly transform the data you get from stdin in ways that are more functional or less, I get it. I didn't downvote or vote to close your question (and I DV and VTC a *lot* of questions in this tag of the form "how do I do X but with functional programming"). I just think the wording of the question (again, this is just written feedback I didn't DV) focuses on entirely the wrong thing. STDIN is an unmoveable unchangeable piece of the puzzle and as such not much worth talking about. It's the data transformation that's interesting.

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of the existing questions. The first link is for reading files. I'm reading from standard in. The second question is not a duplicate since they merely want to read from standard in. They did not qualify it with a lazy read. This question specifically requests not loading the entire standard in into memory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just iterate on `sys.stdin`, it will iterate on the lines.

Then, you can stack generator expressions, or use `map` and `filter` if you prefer. Each line that gets in will go through the pipeline, no list gets built in the process.

Here are examples of each:

```
import sys

stripped_lines = (line.strip() for line in sys.stdin)
lines_with_prompt = ('--> ' + line for line in stripped_lines)
uppercase_lines = map(lambda line: line.upper(), lines_with_prompt)
lines_without_dots = filter(lambda line: '.' not in line, uppercase_lines)

for line in lines_without_dots:
    print(line)
```

And in action, in the terminal:

```
thierry@amd:~$ ./test.py 
My first line
--> MY FIRST LINE 
goes through the pipeline
--> GOES THROUGH THE PIPELINE
but not this one, filtered because of the dot. 
This last one will go through
--> THIS LAST ONE WILL GO THROUGH
```

A shorter example with `map` only, where `map` will iterate on the lines of `stdin`:

```
import sys

uppercase_lines = map(lambda line: line.upper(), sys.stdin)

for line in uppercase_lines:
    print(line)
```

In action:

```
thierry@amd:~$ ./test2.py 
this line will turn
THIS LINE WILL TURN

to uppercase
TO UPPERCASE
```

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know sys.stdin's iterates line by line. I was able to apply your solution to my program.

Comment: "Thanks. I didn't know sys.stdin's iterates line by line." - when chepner said initially, "`sys.stdin` already *is* a lazy iterator of the lines in the file.", **that's what that meant**.