# Python: read from STDIN unless a file is specified, how is it done?

Tags: python-3.x, stdin, argparse

I'm writing a Python script which expects a regex pattern and a file name and looks for that regex pattern within the file.

By default, the script requires a file to work on.

I want to change the script so by default it would take it's input from STDIN unless a file is specified (-f filename).

My code looks like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# This Python script searches for lines matching regular expression -r (--regex) in file/s -f (--files).

import re
import argparse
#import sys

class colored:
   CYAN = '\033[96m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
   END = '\033[0m'

def main(regex, file, underline, color):
    pattern = re.compile(regex)
    try:
        for i, line in enumerate(open(file, encoding="ascii")):
            for match in re.finditer(pattern, line):
                message = "Pattern {} was found on file: {} in line {}. The line is: ".format(regex, file, i+1)
                if args.color and args.underline:
                    #message = "Pattern {} was found on file: {} in line {}. The line is: ".format(regex, file, i+1)
                    l = len(line)
                    print(message + colored.CYAN + line + colored.END, end="")
                    print("                                                                " ,"^" * l)
                    break
                if args.underline:
                    l = len(line)
                    print(message + line, end="")
                    print("                                                                " ,"^" * l)
                    break
                if args.color:
                    print(message + colored.CYAN + line + colored.END, end="")
                    break
                if args.machine:
                    print("{}:{}:{}".format(file, i+1, line), end="")
                    break
                else:
                    print(message + line, end="")
                    break

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("File not found, please supply")
        pass

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Python regex finder', epilog = './python_parser.py --regex [pattern] --files [file]')
    requiredNamed = parser.add_argument_group('required named arguments')
    requiredNamed.add_argument('-r', '--regex',
                        help='regex pattern', required=True)
    parser.add_argument('-f', '--file',
                        help='file to search pattern inside')
    parser.add_argument('-u', '--underline', action='store_true',
                        help='underline')
    parser.add_argument('-c', '--color', action='store_true',
                        help='color')
    parser.add_argument('-m', '--machine', action='store_true',
                        help='machine')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    main(args.regex, args.file, args.underline, args.color)
```

You can see how a run looks [here](https://asciinema.org/a/WjV4AvzFdPJOOpiuNlQJNRYwA).

I tried using the answer [from this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin), but getting the following error:

```
for i, line in enumerate(open(file, encoding="ascii")):
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.TextIOWrapper
```

**Edit #1**:

This is the file:

```
Itai
# something
uuu
UuU
# Itai
# this is a test
this is a test without comment
sjhsg763
3989746
# ddd ksjdj #kkl
```

I get the above error when I supply no file.

**Edit#2**:

When I change the file argument to that:

```
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file',
                        help='file to search pattern inside',
                        default=sys.stdin,
                        type=argparse.FileType('r'),
                        nargs='?'
                        )
```

And then run the script like so:

```
~ echo Itai | ./python_parser.py -r "[a-z]" -m
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./python_parser.py", line 59, in <module>
    main(args.regex, args.file, args.underline, args.color)
  File "./python_parser.py", line 16, in main
    for i, line in enumerate(open(file, encoding="ascii")):
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not NoneType
➜  ~
```

`args.file = tmpfile`

which is a file in the same directory where the script runs.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is `args.file` (or `file`) when you get this error?

Comment: Please check Edit #1, thanks.

Comment: NO, I don't want to see the file.  It want to see the `args.file` value, the one that produces the error.  Also show the code that produces the error, not just a link.

Comment: Please check Edit #2 and thanks again

Comment: FileType gives a file that is already open.  You shouldn't try to open it again.

Comment: But when I run it like so: `echo Itai | ./python_parser.py -r "[a-z]" -m` , no file is being opened... am I wrong? What is the correct way?

Comment: What shall I use then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote this:

```
def main(regex, file, underline, color):
...
        for i, line in enumerate(open(file, encoding="ascii")):
```

You have some confusion about whether `file` denotes a filename or an open file descriptor. You want it to be an open file descriptor, so you may pass in `sys.stdin`. That means `main()` should not attempt to `open()`, rather it should rely on the caller to pass in an already open file descriptor.

Pushing the responsibility for calling `open()` up into `main()` will let you assign `file = sys.stdin` by default, and then re-assign the result of `open()` if it turns out that a filename was specified.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.