# How to read from pipe in Python?

Tags: python, input, pipe

I'm new to Python (not to scripting). On Windows in PowerShell I can write:

```
    PS C:\> (dir -Path C:\junk *.jpg -Recurse).FullName | C:\PS\scripts\EchoPipe.ps1
```

........

In shell: C:\junk\GIMP_TEST\LuminosityMask.JPG

........

Where EchoPipe.ps1 is:

```
    foreach($x in $input) { # Is anything  similar to $input in Python?
        Write-Output('In shell: '+$x)
    }
    Write-Output('... and now I can process them')
```

How to do this in Python?

Q1: The left side of the pipe can be written in this way:

```
    import os
    import re
    for d,x,fl in os.walk('C:\\junk'):
        for f in fl:
            if re.search(r'.jpg$', f, re.I):
                print(d+os.sep+f)
```

Is there a simpler way?

Q2: How to write the equivalent of EchoPipe.ps1 in Python?
    And, most importantly, how to run them using pipeing?
    Do I run it in a Command Prompt or in Python 3... Shell and how?
    Please, be very detailed.

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're looking for. In the `os.walk` loop, you can collect a all filenames matching your regex as a list of strings, and then do something with them directly in Python (open, read, etc.) If you want to actually read from the standard input in a Python script, [there are a few good ways to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin). What exactly are you trying to do with these filenames and/or files?

Answer (score 0):

> foreach($x in $input) { # Is anything  similar to $input in Python?

```
for x in sys.stdin:
    ...
```

will perform line-wise iteration of stdin, blocking when there is no data on the pipe. You can also use dedicated reading methods if you e.g. want larger blocks of data.

> ```
> import os
> import re
> for d,x,fl in os.walk('C:\\junk'):
>     for f in fl:
>         if re.search(r'.jpg$', f, re.I):
>             print(d+os.sep+f)
> ```
>
> Is there a simpler way?
>   Given what you're doing, `fnmatch` is more than sufficient and terser. Also you should use `os.path.join` to join paths.

```py
import fnmatch
import os

for root, _, files in os.walk(...):
    for f in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.jpg'):
        print(os.path.join(root, f))
```

alternatively, and again given what you're doing, recursive globbing would be more than sufficient and much simpler than manually walking the entries:

```py
import pathlib

for path in pathlib.Path('C:\\junk').glob('**/*.jpg'):
    print(path)
```

Comment: Thanks Masklinn for the improvements, I've already made the changes; not pathlib, walk() is more clear than '**'.