# How to 'catch' stdin, stdout, stderr of a program in Python?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, stdout, stdin

I have an `sql.exe` which has a command line interface, takes as input an sql query and prints the results.  I need to write a program in Python, which will generate the sql commands, pass them as input to this program and read the output.

For exercise, I have written a toy program in python, `adder.py`:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    while True:
        try:
            line = input()
            a, b = line.strip().split()
            c = int(a) + int(b)
            print(c)
        except EOFError:
            exit()
        except:
            continue
```

I have created a `in.txt` file:

```
10 5
7 3
1 a
2 1
```

I execute from cmd: `-$ python adder.py < in.txt > out.txt`
and the out.txt is:

```
15
10
3
```

My question is, how can I stream / buffer the input and the output, to constantly communicate with the program, and not have to create and read from files again and again ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use bash pipes and two different functions in your code

Try to rethink your program with this approach.

```sh
./mycode.py -gen | sqlite3 | ./mycode.py -proc
```

1. Your program will accept one command-line argument that selects the behavior
   (generate the input or process the output from SQL)
2. The character `|` is the pipeline operand in Bash
3. The function that process the SQL output must read the `stdin`

#### Command-line arguments

You must read and validate the command-line arguments and choose to execute two different functions.
See here [How to read/process command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009860)

#### Bash pipelines

About pipeline in bash

```
command1 | command2
```

The standard output of `command1` is connected via a pipe to the standard input of `command2`.
Example: `echo "my password" | shasum -a 256`

#### Read from the stdin

See here few examples of how to read the stdin
[How do you read from stdin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin)

#### Example code

See [here](https://onlinegdb.com/SkpujDZUU) an example code.
Below an example output (tested in macOS and Ubunto using SQLite):

```sh
> ./mycode.py -gen
SELECT 0 + 0;
SELECT 1 + 2;
SELECT 2 + 4;
...

> ./mycode.py -gen | sqlite3
0
3
6
...

> # ./mycode.py -proc multiply by 10 the stdin
> ./mycode.py -gen | sqlite3 | ./mycode.py -proc
0
30
60
...
```

Comment: One more thing. The ```sql.exe``` program has the option of exporting a ```table``` into a file with a command like ```> export 'filename.xml' + tablename;```. Is it possible instead of writing to the file, to capture this output in a PIPE ? I have no access to the source code of the ```sql.exe```.

Comment: What SQL implementation are you running? MySQL, SQLite, PostgreSQL, ...?
See the documentation, try this: `man sql.exe` or `sql.exe -h` or `sql.exe --help` or just run `sql.exe` and see how to get help in the command shell.