# python standard input output

Tags: python, input, standards

The function is defined in tempconv.py file as

```
def fahr2cels(fahr) :
    cels = 5/9 * (fahr - 32)
    return cels
```

and there is a text file called tempmax_cels.txt 
which is a line of number.
I want to write a command line in a bash shell like

```sh
python tempconv.py < tempmax_cels.txt
```

so the computer can accept the text file as an standard input.
How can I correct tempconv.py to do it? (using import system module)

Answer (score 0):

This answer gives all the details for your question, better than what i could have done:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38670261/12602635

Comment: If another question gives all the details, you should flag the question as a duplicate.