# Python - Parsing through multiple lines of data from STDIN to store in standard array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, stdin, sys

I have gone through the suggested similar questions, however appear to run into dead-ends; likely because perhaps I am not adequately explaining my problem.
I am attempting to take some STDIN I have access to, which looks like so:

```
0

80
90 29

20
```

What I am having trouble with is taking the integers after the first line and storing them all into a standard Python array.

```
[80, 90, 29, 20]
```

The very first input on the first line will always be some integer 0 or 1, representing the disabling/enabling of some "special feature", any other integers are then input which must be stored to a standard array. As you can see, some integers have lines all to themselves while other lines may have several integers (blank lines should be completely ignored).
I have been attempting to solve this using sys.stdin, since I know after stripping things it already makes the input into list objects, however to little avail.
My code so far is as follows:

```
parse = True
arry = []
print('Special Feature?  (Give 0 to disable feature.)')
feature = input()
print('Please give the input data:')
while parse:
    line = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
    if line == 'quit':
        parse = False
    else:
        arry.append(line)
print('INPUT DATA:', arry)
```

The 'quit' is my attempt at a backdoor I can type by hand since I also don't know how to check for EOF. I know this is very bare-bones (hardly much of anything), but what I effectively wish to produce as my output is this:

```
Special Feature?  (Give 0 to disable feature.)
> 0
Please give the input data:
> 80 90 29 20
INPUT DATA: [80, 90, 29, 20]
```

The lines marked with ">" are not printed, I'm simply demonstrating how the input is conceptually supposed to be read.
Of course, any and all help is appreciated, I look forward to your thoughts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over `sys.stdin` (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/how-do-you-read-from-stdin)).

For storing your numbers, just write any code that will extract them from the strings, and then append the numbers to a list.

Here is an example.

```
import sys
parse = True
arry = []
print('Special Feature?  (Give 0 to disable feature.)')
feature = input()
print('Please give the input data:')
for l in sys.stdin:
    arry += l.strip().split() 
print('INPUT DATA:', arry)
```

Create a new file, for example `data`:

```
0
1 2 3
4 5 6
```

Now try to run the program

```
$ python3 f.py < data
Special Feature?  (Give 0 to disable feature.)
Please give the input data:
INPUT DATA: ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6']
```

Each of the numbers is read from the file.

Comment: My apologies, I neglected to mention that I wanted to print 'INPUT DATA:' with the actual integers and not their string representations. That wasn't any trouble to convert, however, so otherwise this answer was perfect for my needs.
Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to keep `sys.stdin` (despite `input()`), you can use this approach:

```
import sys

parse = True
arry = []
print('Special Feature?  (Give 0 to disable feature.)')
feature = input()
print('Please give the input data:')
while parse:
    line = sys.stdin.readline().rstrip('\n')
    if line == 'quit':
        parse = False
    elif line !='':
        arry += [int(x) for x in line.split()]
print('INPUT DATA:', arry)
```

Input:

```
Special Feature?  (Give 0 to disable feature.)
1
Please give the input data:
10

20

22


1 3 5 0

quit
```

Output (input numbers converted to integers):

```
INPUT DATA: [10, 20, 22, 1, 3, 5, 0]
```

Comment: This was wonderful; another user pointed out I can iterate over sys.stdin without needing to go through .readline() first. However, I do appreciate your maintaining my "backdoor" in the original while condition, as well as the list comprehension. Thank you!