# How do I send Ansible output to a Python script?

Tags: python, ansible

Below I have the Ansible YAML file:

```yaml
- name: "script1"
  command: /home/test/script1.py
  register: output

- name: "script2"
  command: /home/test/script2.py
```

I need `script2.py` to see the output of `script1`.

How would I pass the values from Ansible to `script2`?

Answer (score 1):

[`command`'s `stdin` parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/command_module.html#parameter-stdin) should do the trick:

```yaml
- name: "script1"
  command: /home/test/script1.py
  register: output


- name: "script2"
  command: /home/test/script2.py
  args:
    stdin: "{{ output.stdout }}"
```

Comment: thanks how do I call that in python?

Comment: @user2214162, regarding "How to read STDIN from Python" are already answers on SO like [How do I read from STDIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1450393/).

Comment: Thanks so the command module does not work with my python script so I am usin the shell module instead which does work but still cannot send a variable

Comment: @user2214162, I've updated the code snippet (two last lines)